# How does AMD behave differently than CommonJS

Tags: javascript, module, amd, commonjs

From what I can tell, the differences between CommonJS and AMD are simply that CommonJS requires a static bundle to be made so that all dependencies can be resolved before runtime whereas AMD allows us to load/resolve deps in an async fashion. Just about everything I've read explains the major difference in this way however I am reading Addy Osmani's "Writing Modular JavaScript" and I have a few questions with some of the AMD examples:

### Understanding AMD define():

```
// A module_id (myModule) is used here for demonstration purposes only

define('myModule', 
   ['foo', 'bar'], 
   // module definition function
   // dependencies (foo and bar) are mapped to function parameters
   function ( foo, bar ) {
       // return a value that defines the module export
       // (i.e the functionality we want to expose for consumption)

       // create your module here
       var myModule = {
           doStuff:function(){
               console.log('Yay! Stuff');
           }
       }

       return myModule;
});

// An alternative example could be..
define('myModule', 
   ['math', 'graph'], 
   function ( math, graph ) {

       // Note that this is a slightly different pattern
       // With AMD, it's possible to define modules in a few
       // different ways due as it's relatively flexible with
       // certain aspects of the syntax
       return {
           plot: function(x, y){
               return graph.drawPie(math.randomGrid(x,y));
           }
       }
   };
});
```

---

Now when I read this, I think to myself ok this is different from CommonJS because we pass in a callback function to the define function, so that our callback function is invoked when our dependencies have been loaded/resolved. This allows our callback to be called asynchronously ONLY when everything we need is available..ok cool..Then I read the following example:

### Understanding AMD require():

```
// Consider 'foo' and 'bar' are two external modules
// In this example, the 'exports' from the two modules loaded are passed as
// function arguments to the callback (foo and bar)
// so that they can similarly be accessed

require(['foo', 'bar'], function ( foo, bar ) {
        // rest of your code here
        foo.doSomething();
});
```

### Dynamically-loaded Dependencies

```
define(function ( require ) {
    var isReady = false, foobar;

    // note the inline require within our module definition
    require(['foo', 'bar'], function (foo, bar) {
        isReady = true;
        foobar = foo() + bar();
    });

    // we can still return a module
    return {
        isReady: isReady,
        foobar: foobar
    };
});
```

Now after reading these two examples I'm confused. It seems to say that `require()` is used for dynamically loaded dependencies, however wasn't that the reason we're using AMD/define in the first place? To support async/dynamically loaded deps?? If `require()` allows us to dynamically load deps, then what good is `define()`, or I should say, then how does AMD's `define()` differ from a plain old CJS implementation?